# APNS and iOS - is it possible to deploy several certificates to the Apple Push Notification Server?

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, push, mdm

We are having an app developed for us by a software company. They are telling us that they don't want to store our enterprise APNS certificate, because allegedly this would break the Push Notifications for other customers. Is it true that the developer can have only one certificate to sign their apps?

The app that is being developed is supposed to be published in two ways - for the general audience - via Apple App Store, and internally a branded version of the same app.

Push notifications work well on the official app, but when we distribute the IPA file internally, the app doesn't work. They are telling us that if they used our certificate for APNS, this would would work for us, but not for other customers.
Is that correct, or are we misunderstanding how the APNS works?

Comment: Technically you're supposed to have TWO environments.. One for development and one for production.. IE: Sandbox and Production.. So they're talking nonsense.. However, if their server only "supports" one certificate at a time, then they will break it if they CHANGE that certificate to the enterprise one.. I recommend using the JWT HTTP2.0 version anyway instead of using certificates (Then you don't have to worry about certificates at all).. but that's entirely up to you and what their server supports.

Comment: How are you distributing the app internally?

Answer (score 0):

Is it true that the developer can have only one certificate to sign their apps?
- No . Developers can sign apps using different certificate of different account. If you have enterprise account then they will sign app using certificate created using your account.

They are telling us that if they used our certificate for APNS, this would would work for us, but not for other customers.
- Generally when we create apps for APNS it will work for everyone. Hence it will possible to work for everyone.